# Spring boot: path to application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Let's say I want to load the application.properties from /tmp/application.properties. How do I do it when I usually execute the app with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I read all docs and stackoverflow posts but I cannot get it working.
Usually I find:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=<path-to-file> myBootProject.jar
```

But this does not seem to work when executing via mvn-spring-boot:run.
I also tried without success:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.config.location=/tmp/application.properties"
```

Answer (score 6):

The `spring-boot:run` goal has an optional parameter that is used exactly for that purpose: `spring-boot.run.arguments`.

In your case, the property you want to configure is `--spring.config.location=<path-to-file>`. So you can use the following command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.location=<path-to-file>
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#arguments

Comment: There's a baeldung article that incorrectly says `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.config.location="file:///Users/home/application.properties"` works.  That led me and many others down a frustrating path.  Thanks for showing the right way to do it!